# show modal dialog from table

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

In my page I am trying to display a jquery modal dialog, pressing a cell in a table. The problem is not shown by pressing an item. I put a button and if it works when clicking, but since the table does not work.
I also tried adding the following code:

```
<div data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" data-target="#orderModal" class="cal1">
```

This code causes all table cells display the same modal dialog, and do not want that.

I want the modal show it some cells that are specified, not all.
So I added the code to each td

`<td data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" data-target="#orderModal" class="day past calender-day-2015-05-01"><div class="day-contents">1</div></td>`

but does not work, and I'm sure it should work.

I appreciate your help or suggestions about how to fix it.
Regards!

My web demo: http://pedregal09.co.nf/programa/index.html

Here is my template code:
http://pastebin.com/raw/c9Y8awuh

Comment: The pastebin link is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors in your javascript, event variable you using is undefined.
You need always first to use javascript console in browser to check for javascript errors.

```
    $(function(){
        $('#orderModal').modal({
            keyboard: true,
            backdrop: "static",
            show:false
        }).on('show', function(event){
            var getIdFromRow = $(event.target).closest('tr').data('id');
            //make your ajax call populate items or what even you need
            $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Order Id selected: ' + getIdFromRow  + '</b>'))
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your code you trigger the modal twice when you click in a column. First you have:

```
<div data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" data-target="#orderModal" class="cal1">
```

And then:

```
<td data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" data-target="#orderModal" class="day past calender-day-2015-05-01"><div class="day-contents">1</div></td>
```

Remove the trigger from the "div" and it will work.